# Javascript: automatic conversion from 1xn 2d array to vector of length n

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

I'm reading some values from a local database using ado in IE8 and generating a 2d array. I want the first index of this array to be the field and the second to be the row. For this reason, even when there is only one field or one row, I want a 2 dimensional array. The following code adequately describes the process I'm using to create the array:

```
function test() {
  var a = new Array(1);
  alert(a.length); // 1
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
    a[0,i] = i;
  alert(a.length); // 10
}
```

Before the loop, the array length is 1. Afterward it is 10. This means when I want a 1xn array, I get a vector of length n.

I don't even have access to other browsers to see if this happens elsewhere. I'm very constrained in my tools, but that's another story.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Matt

Comment: The comma operator evaluates each expression and returns the result of the last one. Thus, `a[0,i]` is effectively `a[i]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
function test() {
    var a = [[]]; // create an array within an array using shorthand notation, don't use new Array().

    // a clearer way to explain the above is this:
    // var a = []; // create an empty array with shorthand notation
    // a[0] = []; // create an empty array as the first element of a

    alert(a.length); // 1

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[0][i] = i;
    }

    alert(a.length); // 1
}​
```

Because Javascript doesn't have true multidimensional arrays, you'll have to access the second array with `a[0][i]`, not `a[0, i]`. This is because you're really creating an array of arrays.

Comment: `a[0]` is `undefined` though.

Comment: and the 1 x n array would still have n elements -- I'm confused as to why that's an issue.

Comment: @JeremyGoodell: Not true. A `1 x n` array would have one element, that element being a second array.

Comment: In your answer: `don't use new Array()`, is there any real benefit for the shorthand notation besides allowing you to create a sub-array and being easier to type/saving a couple bytes of data? Or just convention? Just wondering.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté The `Array` constructor is a really bad API design and it should be avoided. It does absolutely no good to pre-allocate "slots" in a JavaScript array in any modern interpreter.

Comment: @Fabrício: It's good practice, since the constructor function is ambiguous. `new Array(5)` behaves differently than `new Array('foo')`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: What Pointy said. Plus, it's less typing, looks cleaner, and is generally less confusing. Particularly because if you pass a number `n` into `new Array()` you'll get an array of `n` length. If you pass anything else into it you'll get an array with one element, that being the passed-in value.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll switch from `new Array()` to the shorthand for my future projects, thanks. :)

Comment: I had expected that would be the way to index arrays of arrays. JS syntax is very c-like for this sort of activity. However, I'd seen examples elsewhere with [x,y] notation- hence using that. Never trust the internet (yes, this is supposed to be a little ironic). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hehehe, no problem. Glad I could be of service to you.

Comment: "It does absolutely no good to pre-allocate "slots" in a JavaScript array in any modern interpreter."

Why is this? Seems a little odd to me.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I happened to come back to this question. The reason to not use `new Array()` is because the interpreter must look up the context chain to determine whether the programmer has replaced the function `Array` for the current scope. For example, I could write `function Array() {return 0;}`. So whenever I use `arr = new Array()` the interpreter must determine whether I've redefined the `Array` function in my current scope. In comparison, when I use `arr = [];` the interpreter immediately knows I'm creating an array, and as the programmer I cannot alter the syntax of the language.

Comment: @mkingston Yes, I've figured that out since my comment here, but thanks for the in-depth comment/answer. `=]`

Comment: Hey look, it's a programmers' reunion. :D Really it's a testimony to the design of Stack Overflow that the three of us have all been on for over a year and can comment within minutes of each other on a post over a year old.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not know multidimensional arrays. Therefore, you need:

```
var a = new Array(1);
alert(a.length); // 1
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) { // useless :-)
    a[i] = new Array;
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        a[0][j] = j;
}
alert(a.length); // 1
```

The code might be easier to understand using the array shorthand notation:

```
var a = [new Array(10)];
for (var i=0; i<a[0].length; i++)
    a[0][i] = i;
alert(a.length); // 1
```

Your approach with `a[0,i]` is interpreted as a [expression sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which evaluates to `i`, so would be equivalent to `a[i]`.